# How to bound max of abs. val. of sums of random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_1, . . . , X_n$ be independent random variables on
$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathrm{P})$. Assume that $\mathbb{E}X_i = 0$ and $\sigma_k^2 = \mathbb{E}X_k^2 < \infty$ for each $k = 1,2,... n$.

Prove that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, we have
$$
\mathrm{P}\left(\,\max_{1 \leq k \leq n}\left\vert\,S_{k}\,\right\vert \geq \epsilon\,\right) \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^{2}}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\sigma_k^{2}
$$

where $S_k = X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_k$.

At first, I thought I could use some variation of a Chebyshev / Markov type inequality, but I can't seem to make that work.  I have been banging my head on this problem for quite awhile and without knowing more information (such as the value of $\mathbb{E}|X_i|$), I do not know how to proceed.  Any and all help appreciated.

**Additional:**  I'm not sure if this is a productive route of thinking for this problem, but I was wondering if proving some more general results about probabilities / distributions of absolute values of random variables and/or max's of random variables may help, as I am having trouble seeing how I can extract much information about those entities given what I know in the problem above.  However, I cannot seem to find any useful reference material on relevant properties of absolute values or max's of RV's.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_inequality